# Demosaicing an RCCB color filter array

Tags: colorfilter, rawimage, demosaicing

I am looking for techniques that allow me to demosaic an RCCB CFA.

I came across this paper on SPIE "Color image acquisition method using color filter arrays occupying overlapped color spaces" that gives a good technique to  convert to interpolate the missing color values for an RCCB CFA. The result is what the authors refer to as an RWB image.

However, in the paper, they say that  moving from RWB to RGB is a simple linear transformation. Other sources state that a suitable color correction matrix needs to be applied to move from this RWB image to RGB. But, I am not sure how to actually compute this value for any RAW image with RCCB layout.

Is it possible to compute this color correction matrix (CCM) using the ICC profile or any other metadata that is part of the RAW file? Or is this something the creator of the image has to know.

Would love some ideas.